# Some of our users cannot receive FCM token

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

We had logged our users who cannot receive tokens and got this error:
`Error=INVALID_PARAMETERS'. It is missing 'token' field." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Invalid registration response :'Error=INVALID_PARAMETERS'. It is missing 'token' field.` That's because of we're missing FCM token. How can we ensure that each and every user gets FCM token for sure?

We did write up to date code according to tutorial.

Comment: We had same logs, it was only on iOS devices - maybe look here: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#registerDeviceForRemoteMessages